# I'm having problems with video vtt where the subtitles are not showing up

Tags: html

html

```
 WEBVTT
```

00:01.000 --> 00:8.000
you dont have

help me

Comment: Your `vtt` is not a `vtt` it is a `txt`.

Comment: Please clarify question and provide exact code. The `you dont have` doesnt make sense and previous data seemed like browser was outdated, perhaps not supporting HTML5? Also using ``src="C:\...`` might cause permission issues, not sure though (not a windows user).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with your file extension: 
**video.vtt.txt** <- the file format you are using 
**video.vtt** <- the file format you should be using